# LEFT JOIN and ORDER BY Strange error

Tags: mysql

I got a strange error when I upgrade MSQL from 5 to 6
My script create database

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `table1` (`id`, `value`) VALUES 
  (1, 100),
  (2, 200),
  (3, 300);
CREATE TABLE `table1_use` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `table1id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `uid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `table1_use` (`id`, `table1id`, `uid`) VALUES 
  (1, 1, 99);
```

And I have two query (one of has order by)

```
select
      temp.sel
from
    table1 t1
    left join (
         select *,1 as sel from table1_use t1u where t1u.`table1id`=1
    ) temp on temp.table1id = t1.id
order by t1.value
------
select
      temp.sel
from
    table1 t1
    left join (
         select *,1 as sel from table1_use t1u where t1u.`table1id`=1
    ) temp on temp.table1id = t1.id
```

Why result different in 2 query (MYSQL 6.xx)
Result with SQL 1

```
sel
1
1
1
```

Result with SQL 2

```
sel
1
null
null
```

Comment: can you add result in your question and the strange error?

Comment: In query with order by, all result is 1. In query with out order by all result is null (MySql 5: both is null)

Comment: Can you execute `SELECT VERSION();` on each MySQL Server and publish the result?

Comment: Mysql 5.7.17-0 returns 1,1,1 for the statement with the order clause and 1,null,null for statement without order clause. Mariadb 10.1.14 returns null,null,null for the statement with the order statement and 1,null,null for the statement without the order clause - looks like a bug which has been looked at but not successfully resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems somewhat related to optimizer behavior. See [9.9.2 Controlling Switchable Optimizations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/switchable-optimizations.html).

```sql
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.17    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table1_use`, `table1`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table1` (
    ->   `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    ->   `value` int(11) NOT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `table1` (`id`, `value`) VALUES 
    ->   (1, 100),
    ->   (2, 200),
    ->   (3, 300);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table1_use` (
    ->   `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    ->   `table1id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `uid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `table1_use` (`id`, `table1id`, `uid`) VALUES 
    ->   (1, 1, 99);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT @@optimizer_switch\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
@@optimizer_switch:
index_merge=on,
index_merge_union=on,
index_merge_sort_union=on,
index_merge_intersection=on,
engine_condition_pushdown=on,
index_condition_pushdown=on,
mrr=on,
mrr_cost_based=on,
block_nested_loop=on,
batched_key_access=off,
materialization=on,
semijoin=on,
loosescan=on,
firstmatch=on,
duplicateweedout=on,
subquery_materialization_cost_based=on,
use_index_extensions=on,
condition_fanout_filter=on,
derived_merge=on
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT 
    ->   `temp`.`sel`
    -> FROM
    ->   `table1` `t1`
    ->   LEFT JOIN (
    ->     SELECT *, 1 `sel` FROM `table1_use` `t1u` WHERE `t1u`.`table1id` = 1
    ->   ) `temp` ON `temp`.`table1id` = `t1`.`id`
    -> ORDER BY `t1`.`value`;
+------+
| sel  |
+------+
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `temp`.`sel`
    -> FROM
    ->   `table1` `t1`
    ->   LEFT JOIN (
    ->     SELECT *, 1 `sel` FROM `table1_use` `t1u` WHERE `t1u`.`table1id` = 1
    ->   ) `temp` ON `temp`.`table1id` = `t1`.`id`;
+------+
| sel  |
+------+
|    1 |
| NULL |
| NULL |
+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET optimizer_switch='block_nested_loop=off';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @@optimizer_switch\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
@@optimizer_switch:
index_merge=on,
index_merge_union=on,
index_merge_sort_union=on,
index_merge_intersection=on,
engine_condition_pushdown=on,
index_condition_pushdown=on,
mrr=on,
mrr_cost_based=on,
block_nested_loop=off,
batched_key_access=off,
materialization=on,
semijoin=on,
loosescan=on,
firstmatch=on,
duplicateweedout=on,
subquery_materialization_cost_based=on,
use_index_extensions=on,
condition_fanout_filter=on,
derived_merge=on
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT 
    ->   `temp`.`sel`
    -> FROM
    ->   `table1` `t1`
    ->   LEFT JOIN (
    ->     SELECT *, 1 `sel` FROM `table1_use` `t1u` WHERE `t1u`.`table1id` = 1
    ->   ) `temp` ON `temp`.`table1id` = `t1`.`id`
    -> ORDER BY `t1`.`value`;
+------+
| sel  |
+------+
|    1 |
| NULL |
| NULL |
+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `temp`.`sel`
    -> FROM
    ->   `table1` `t1`
    ->   LEFT JOIN (
    ->     SELECT *, 1 `sel` FROM `table1_use` `t1u` WHERE `t1u`.`table1id` = 1
    ->   ) `temp` ON `temp`.`table1id` = `t1`.`id`;
+------+
| sel  |
+------+
|    1 |
| NULL |
| NULL |
+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**From MySQL 5.7.7**, see [9.9.3 Optimizer Hints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizer-hints.html).

```sql
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table1_use`, `table1`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table1` (
    ->   `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    ->   `value` int(11) NOT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `table1` (`id`, `value`) VALUES 
    ->   (1, 100),
    ->   (2, 200),
    ->   (3, 300);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table1_use` (
    ->   `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    ->   `table1id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `uid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `table1_use` (`id`, `table1id`, `uid`) VALUES 
    ->   (1, 1, 99);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @@optimizer_switch\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
@@optimizer_switch: 
index_merge=on,
index_merge_union=on,
index_merge_sort_union=on,
index_merge_intersection=on,
engine_condition_pushdown=on,
index_condition_pushdown=on,
mrr=on,
mrr_cost_based=on,
block_nested_loop=on,
batched_key_access=off,
materialization=on,
semijoin=on,
loosescan=on,
firstmatch=on,
duplicateweedout=on,
subquery_materialization_cost_based=on,
use_index_extensions=on,
condition_fanout_filter=on,
derived_merge=on
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   /*+ NO_BNL(@`subquery`) */ `temp`.`sel`
    -> FROM
    ->   `table1` `t1`
    ->   LEFT JOIN (
    ->     SELECT /*+ QB_NAME(`subquery`) */ *, 1 `sel`
    ->     FROM `table1_use` `t1u`
    ->     WHERE `t1u`.`table1id` = 1
    ->   ) `temp` ON `temp`.`table1id` = `t1`.`id`
    -> ORDER BY `t1`.`value`;
+------+
| sel  |
+------+
|    1 |
| NULL |
| NULL |
+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**MariaDB 10.1.21**, see [optimizer_switch](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/optimizer-switch/) and [RESET](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/reset/).

```sql
MariaDB [_]> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------------+
| VERSION()       |
+-----------------+
| 10.1.21-MariaDB |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [_]> SELECT 
    ->   `temp`.`sel`
    -> FROM
    ->   `table1` `t1`
    ->   LEFT JOIN (
    ->     SELECT *, 1 `sel` FROM `table1_use` `t1u` WHERE `t1u`.`table1id` = 1
    ->   ) `temp` ON `temp`.`table1id` = `t1`.`id`
    -> ORDER BY `t1`.`value`;
+------+
| sel  |
+------+
| NULL |
| NULL |
| NULL |
+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [_]> SELECT 
    ->   `temp`.`sel`
    -> FROM
    ->   `table1` `t1`
    ->   LEFT JOIN (
    ->     SELECT *, 1 `sel` FROM `table1_use` `t1u` WHERE `t1u`.`table1id` = 1
    ->   ) `temp` ON `temp`.`table1id` = `t1`.`id`;
+-----+
| sel |
+-----+
|   1 |
| NULL |
| NULL |
+-----+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [_]> SET optimizer_switch='outer_join_with_cache=off';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [_]> RESET QUERY CACHE;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [_]> SELECT 
    ->   `temp`.`sel`
    -> FROM
    ->   `table1` `t1`
    ->   LEFT JOIN (
    ->     SELECT *, 1 `sel` FROM `table1_use` `t1u` WHERE `t1u`.`table1id` = 1
    ->   ) `temp` ON `temp`.`table1id` = `t1`.`id`
    -> ORDER BY `t1`.`value`;
+-----+
| sel |
+-----+
|   1 |
| NULL |
| NULL |
+-----+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [_]> SELECT 
    ->   `temp`.`sel`
    -> FROM
    ->   `table1` `t1`
    ->   LEFT JOIN (
    ->     SELECT *, 1 `sel` FROM `table1_use` `t1u` WHERE `t1u`.`table1id` = 1
    ->   ) `temp` ON `temp`.`table1id` = `t1`.`id`;
+-----+
| sel |
+-----+
|   1 |
| NULL |
| NULL |
+-----+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: When I set 'block_nested_loop=off', It work, but system seem slow a little